# Android Studio: LogCat doesn't show some Logs anymore after reconnection of the device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-logcat

currently I am developing an App, which needs a USB-Connection to another device. So my only USB-Port on the Tablet is blocked while testing. So far everything worked fine with the Logcat. I disconnected the Tablet from my PC, tested the app, reconnected it and had the saved logcat from the device. So my debugging happened via Logcat.

Recently that method does not work anymore. Some of the Logs are showing up, some don't. I know that there should be some Logs, because the action of the device that I am testing with, indicates that the process has passed some Log-Outputs. But most of the Log-Outputs simply don't show up. I recognized, that it depends on the class. So if (for example) one Log of the Main-Activity is showing up. The rest of the Logs withhin this Activity doing so as well. But all Logs of other Activities or Services aren't.

Has anybody an idea how to get this working again, or at least how to debug my app with an other device connected to the tablet (OTG-Adapter won't work because the connected device, as well as my PC wan't to be Master).

Thanks for any help,
Daniel

Comment: try TCP-IP connection to connect your device ADB then you will be connected.

Comment: Please check the following in logcat tab
1) Make sure that there is no filter added
2) Make sure there is not text in search box
3) Make sure verbose chose instead of error/warning